# After Magento2 Community to Enterprise edition migration in that process getting error

Tags: patch, enterprise

Unable to apply data patch Magento\CatalogStaging\Setup\Patch\Data\MigrateCatalogProducts for module Magento_CatalogStaging. Original exception message: URL key for specified store already exists.

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: I removed duplicate urls from url_rewrite table

Comment: I have deleted all the rows but still throws this error.